# Hide and unhide rows based on a value

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to create a survey in Excel and want to hide and unhide rows based on their answers. For example, if D3 = "no" hide rows D4:D10, and I want to repeat this multiple times throughout, but the number of rows to hide changes. So if D3 = "yes" leave unhidden. Then move to answer D5, if D5 = "no" hide rows D6:D7. And this continues on and on throughout.

Comment: Search this site for Worksheet_Change and Hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `worksheet_change()` event. In your VBE double click the worksheet where this change (this cell) will happen. Then enter:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Detect if the worksheet change was on cell D3
    If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("D3")) Is Nothing) Then
        'Hide rows if the value of D3 is "No"
        Range("D4:D10").EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("D3").Value = "No")
    End If
End Sub
```

Every time a change happens on this worksheet this subroutine will fire off, test if the change occured in cell "D2" then toggle the row's hidden property based on the value.

The `Hidden` property of the `EntireRow` range object takes a `True` or `False` value, so we are able to just set it equal to the result of the conditional statement `(Range("D3").value = "No")` which will return a `True` or `False` greatly simplifying the amount of code you need to write.

You'll just need to add more `If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("whatever")) Is Nothing) Then` lines to test for your other cells like `D5` and hide the appropriate rows base on whatever value you are testing for in that cell.

If that gets to be too much code (testing all those intersects) you can just test the intersects once like:

```
If Not (Intersect(Target, Union(Range("D3"), Range("D5"), Range("D8"))) Is Nothing) Then
    'And then in here your individual lines that toggle the hidden property:
    Range("D4:D10").EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("D3").Value = "No")

    Range("D6:D7").EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("D5").Value = "No")

    ...
End If
```

Lastly, because this beast will fire any time any change is made on this worksheet, you may want to shut off event firing while the subroutine is running. So turn `enableEvents` off at the top of the subroutine and turn it back on at the end:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not (Intersect(Target, Union(Range("D3"), Range("D5"), Range("D8"))) Is Nothing) Then            
        Range("D4:D10").EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("D3").Value = "No")    
        Range("D6:D7").EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("D5").Value = "No")
        Range("D9:D12").EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("D8").Value = "No")    
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This will prevent this same subroutine getting called by itself while it's busy changing the sheet causing an infinite loop and locking up excel (which sucks if you didn't save the workbook before firing it off).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I tried using the code above, but unfortunately it did not work for me. I press run when there is a "no" in D3 but the rows underneath are not hidden.

Comment: You don't press run. This worksheet_change event code runs automatically when the worksheet changes. Make sure the code is not in a module, but rather in the worksheet's code (by double clicking the worksheet in the VBA project pane in VBE)

Comment: I made sure it was in the worksheet, but nothing is happening.

Comment: Try saving the sheet, closing, and reopening. Sometimes these event triggered macros are picky.

Comment: It was the If Not  the code  I needed to get rid of the Not and just say If to make it work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Boy... That sounds like not a great idea. I think the problem is the range you are testing for intersection with Target, but... If it's working for you, then go for it.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? Is this a best practice?

Comment: That is a check to insure that only D3 was changed as opposed to every other cell on the sheet. By taking the NOT off you are saying: "go ahead and run the rest of this code if the changed cell is any cell except for D3" so every time you sneeze near that sheet it will run the code, which is expensive, processing-wise.